# Linha abaixo do texto

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando colocar uma linha abaixo do título h3, só que respeitando o tamanho da linha de 100px e de acordo como justificado à esquerda ou à direita.

Desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, quando a resolução da tela diminui (como por exemplo 1029px), as linhas que estão alinhadas a direita não acompanham e se deslocam.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu código é (porém não funciona corretamente):

```css
.box-geral-esquerda div.box-texto h3, .box-geral-direita div.box-texto h3 {
    font-size:22px;
    color:#27461f;
    line-height:42px;
}

.box-geral-esquerda div.box-texto h3:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #27461f;
    width: 100px;
    left:10px;
    top:68px
}

.box-geral-direita div.box-texto h3:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #27461f;
    width: 100px;
    right:190px;
    top:130px
}
```

```html
<div class="box-geral-esquerda">
  <div class="box-texto">
    <h3>CORPORATIVO LOREM IPSUM</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box-geral-direita">
  <div class="box-texto">
    <h3>CORPORATIVO LOREM IPSUM</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou colocar `position: relative` nos `H3` para que os pseudo-elementos, que são as linhas, se posicionem absolutamente dentro dos `H3`. Com isso, basta usar `bottom` e `left`, para as linhas à esquerda, e `bottom` e `right` para as linhas à direita, todos com valor `0`.

```css
.box-geral-direita div.box-texto h3{
   text-align: right;
}

.box-geral-esquerda div.box-texto h3, .box-geral-direita div.box-texto h3 {
    font-size:22px;
    color:#27461f;
    line-height:42px;
    position: relative;
}

.box-geral-esquerda div.box-texto h3:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #27461f;
    width: 100px;
    left:0;
    bottom:0
}

.box-geral-direita div.box-texto h3:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #27461f;
    width: 100px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0
}
```

```html
<div class="box-geral-esquerda">
  <div class="box-texto">
    <h3>CORPORATIVO LOREM IPSUM</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box-geral-direita">
  <div class="box-texto">
    <h3>CORPORATIVO LOREM IPSUM</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```